# How to keep 2 fields using django forms

Tags: django, web, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-templates

As django forms run a loop for the fields

```
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="col-6">
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        {{ field.label_tag }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

I actually want to have 2 fields, I found a cheap solution to this issue using Bootstrap4
I created the columns by using **col-6** by which I get 2 fields in the row. But what if I want to make custom designs of forms in django ?

[image: Like I have this sample from UI team]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i am using this method to show only fields i want and then have if statements for the way each field should be shown

```
{% for i in form %}
    {% if i.name in 'title,address,city' (Fields you want to show) %}
        {% for error in i.errors %}
            <div>
                <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <p>
            <label>{{i.label}}:</label>
                <input type="text" name="{{i.name}}" required id="id_{{i.name}}">
        </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And like that you can style it however you want and show only those you want to show

Comment: Oh! Wow Thanks a lot, I am quite new to Django templates. So this was a huge help

Comment: You're welcome , You can upvote the answer if you find it useful oor accept it if you think that it solves your problem

Comment: What if I want to go by indexes ?

Comment: Indexes ? Like 1st item and 2nd and all ?

Comment: Yeah, like 2-3 in one row, 1 in the next like that

Comment: Just use css to do that